# .htaccess RedirectMatch redirects all pages like "something"

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect

`mysite.com/something`

to

`othersite.com/someone`

I am using this (in htaccess):

`RedirectMatch 301 /something http://othersite.com/someone`

but it redirects all pages like mysite.com/ksadkahsdhasdhkas/something and I want to redirect only mysite.com/something

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex anchors `^` and `$` to make sure you don't match any unwanted URI:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/something/?$ http://othersite.com/someone
```

Comment: Thank you! What does the `?` means?

Comment: I used `/?$` to make trailing slash optional. In regex `?` means match 0 or 1 times.